# when i run yarn install i am getting this error error Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@sentry/cli/-/cli-1.74.4.tgz: Request failed "403 Forbidden"

Tags: react-native

[error on yarn install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWJnk.png)

after i cloned the repo and on running the command yarn install the below occurs
error Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@sentry/cli/-/cli-1.74.4.tgz: Request failed "403 Forbidden"
In addition to the above the previous I have created are working fine but when I am trying to make a new project the template is not getting downloaded properly